# Putting the comment on a fb page

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, graph-api-explorer

I am using js sdk to commment on every post which is being posted by any user on my FB Page. 
I made one app and one FB page.
I put some posts on FB page but i am not able to comment on posts. I am using Graph API Explorer : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to test the functionality.

I have got the token with extended permission and then i tried :

```
page_id/feed?fields=id,from
```

I got all the posts and then i tried to the comment on a post using :

```
post_id/comments?message="Test Comment"
```

I got

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

which should instead return the **comment id** of new comment having message Test Comment.

Any Help will be highly appreciated !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, i was using GET request , instead use POST request

```
post_id/comments?message=Test Comment.
```

It will return the new comment ID.